# Adding data to Clever maps trough KEboola goes wrong

Tags: clevermaps

My problem is that when I try to run addMetadata from json file it is showing this error. Can you please help me to solve my problem?
[

```js
Error description=Field '$.ref.properties[41].column' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[20].column' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[37].name' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[33].column' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[38].name' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[21].name' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[3].column' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[6].name' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[26].name' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[32].name' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[8].name' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[23].name' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[4].name' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[35].name' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[33].name' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[39].name' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[28].column' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[1].name' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[3].name' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[17].name' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[27].column' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[19].name' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[4].column' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[10].column' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[22].column' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[40].column' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[21].column' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[32].column' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[0].column' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[24].column' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[15].column' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[29].name' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[14].name' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[40].name' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[25].name' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[29].column' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[36].column' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[5].column' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[7].name' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[28].name' must match ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$, Field '$.ref.properties[37].column' must match
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dv8l.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is setup of that dataset *sreality_output_mapped.json* ?
Does the names of columns in that dataset starts with letter (lowercase)?

Comment: no we dont have the column names in lowercase. Will do. Thank you :)